# How to set value in out parameter in oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I want to create a stored procedure on oracle which return the value in a out parameter. I was able to create a sample query but I am able to set the value to output variable. And the output should be converted into JSON

Here is my code

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_TABLE_NAMES(JSON_DATA OUT CLOB )
  --  OUT OUT_IS_SUCCESS BOOLEAN,
  --  OUT OUT_ERROR_MESSAGE VARCHAR(4000)
AS
l_cursor_1 SYS_REFCURSOR;


BEGIN

--JSON_DATA :=
    OPEN l_cursor_1 FOR SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(
          JSON_OBJECT('TABLE_NAME' VALUE T.TABLE_NAME)
        ) INTO JSON_DATA
     FROM
        (
       select TABLE_NAME FROM all_tables 
    ) T 
; 

JSON_DATA := TO_CLOB(l_cursor_1);
--dbms_sql.return_result(l_cursor_1);

END GET_TABLE_NAMES;
```

I want to get output in 3 variables
JSON_DATA contain out in JSON format
OUT_IS_SUCCESS Boolean flag if no error occurred
OUT_ERROR_MESSAGE if any error message

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: You've tagged this question for Oracle 11g, but you're using `json_arryagg()` and imply the query is working - but that function wasn't added until 12cR2. Which Oracle version are you actually using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell `json_arrayagg` to return a CLOB, and select that directly into your OUT parameter. The other two commented-out parameters are malformed; the `OUT` is in the wrong place, and the string should not have a size.

You can do something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_TABLE_NAMES(
  P_JSON_DATA OUT CLOB,
  P_IS_SUCCESS OUT BOOLEAN,
  P_ERROR_MESSAGE OUT VARCHAR2
)
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(
      JSON_OBJECT('TABLE_NAME' VALUE TABLE_NAME)
      FORMAT JSON
      RETURNING CLOB
    )
  INTO P_JSON_DATA
  FROM all_tables;

  P_IS_SUCCESS := TRUE;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    P_IS_SUCCESS := FALSE;
    P_ERROR_MESSAGE := SQLERRM;
END GET_TABLE_NAMES;
/
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2cb578f5f6af9696488b17e51e08dfeb), with an extra bit of dummy code to force an exception on the second call.

But catching exceptions, particularly with `when others`, just to turn them into basic strings with no context such as the position the error occurred, is rarely a good idea - it would be simpler to just let any exception flow back to the caller:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_TABLE_NAMES(
  P_JSON_DATA OUT CLOB
)
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(
      JSON_OBJECT('TABLE_NAME' VALUE TABLE_NAME)
      FORMAT JSON
      RETURNING CLOB
    )
  INTO P_JSON_DATA
  FROM all_tables;
END GET_TABLE_NAMES;
/
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fea3cbec0ff33e97072fd0c35a41f551)

... unless you have a good reason to hide useful debugging information.

Comment: Hi @Alex Thanks! This solved my problem.

Can you help me here as well. what is the alternative for TABLE_NAME = CONCAT('', TABLENAME,'')) I am using this parameter TABLENAME as an input parameter to apply filter in the select statement in stored procedure in the WHERE clause. How can I achieve this in oracle?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, or why you would want to add empty strings to the value - which has no overall effect. You should ask a new question explaining what you are trying to do and include your current code, and the problem you are having.

Comment: Hi @Alex. Sure. Thanks! Will do the same